# Read from a 'named pipe' / fifo with Node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, macos, named-pipes

I have this:

```
  const p = path.resolve(projectRoot + '/NAMEDPIPEIN');
  const fd = fs.openSync(p, 'r+');

  fs.createReadStream(null, {fd}).on('data', function (d) {
    if (String(d).trim() === '[stdin end]') {
      return process.nextTick(cb);
    }
    process.argv.push(String(d).trim());
  });
```

I start the Node.js process, and then later, I write to the named pipe. For some reason no data seems to be arriving in the on data callback.

I am writing to named pipe like so:

```
 mkfifo NAMEDPIPEIN
 echo "foo bar baz" > NAMEDPIPEIN
```

Comment: Did you try [this suggestion](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3628#issuecomment-152974804) for Linux?

Comment: thanks, trying it right now...wondering if it will work on mac

Comment: According to that thread it (most likely) will not work anywhere but Linux.

Comment: Your code works just fine on my Mac (in that the `data` event fires whenever I write some data to the named pipe). As an aside, wouldn't `child_process.spawn()` be a solution to whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: in my case I have a daemon process. I need to send the daemon process some commands. The easiest way it seems to do IPC on both macos and linux is named pipes, as far as I can tell. Not having an easy time figure it out though.

Comment: @mscdex the example you linked to does indeed work, I tried it. Using net.Socket.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other solution, from [@richardpringle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965930/1843507) should work, but is limited in functionality.

If you try to open multiple FIFOs that way (more than the number of threads in the thread-pool), the first ones you opened won't be streaming data anymore. This is because the `fs` module isn't designed to work with file-descriptors in non-blocking mode. Instead, use the `net` module!

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/52622722/1843507 the current way to achieve streaming from a FIFO is using a socket:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const net = require('net');

fs.open('path/to/fifo/', fs.constants.O_RDONLY | fs.constants.O_NONBLOCK, (err, fd) => {
  // Handle err
  const pipe = new net.Socket({ fd });
  // Now `pipe` is a stream that can be used for reading from the FIFO.
  pipe.on('data', (data) => {
    // process data ...
  });
});
```

In summary, you can use [@richardpringle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965930/1843507)'s solution if you are running a script and don't mind tying up one of the threads in the thread-pool. Otherwise, you should definitely use this solution.

Comment: you can make this a quick synchronous function to replace fs.create*Stream by using O_RDWR and openSync

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const fifoPath = path.resolve(projectRoot, '/NAMEDPIPEIN')

const fifo = fs.createReadStream(fifoPath);

fifo.on('data', data => {
  // process data...
});
```

Use `fifo.on('data', console.log)` for testing.

Comment: I also recommend setting the file stream encoding with `fifo.setEncoding('utf8')`

Comment: if you write to the named pipe once, it seems to stop working after that

Comment: checkout @Sami's answer, it's more robust!

Comment: Since you're just using `.on('data')`, will it also work if I use `.pipe()`?

Comment: Yes, it will as it's just an instance of ReadableStream

Comment: The problem I currently have is that nodejs will not exit unless someone connects and writes SOMETHING to the named pipe. Otherwise, it will hang forever forcing you to kill nodejs. I'll try the net solution give in the other answer.